# Why am I getting conversion exception in this code for xstream?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

I've the following test code which is not working.

```
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xStream.alias(clazz.getName(), clazz);
    String test="<list><Person><lastname>abcd</lastname><phone><code>123</code><number>1234-456</number></phone><fax><code>123</code><number>9999-999</number></fax></Person></list>";
    Object object = xStream.fromXML(test);


    clazz=Arraylist.class
```

Exception Information:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Person : Person : Person : Person
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Person : Person
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : Person : Person
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
path                : /list/Person
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that XStream doesn't know what `Person` is, which makes sense because you haven't aliased it anywhere.

Try adding

```
xStream.alias("Person", Person.class);
```

Comment: Yeah I had done this too and after this I get Null Pointer Exception for Class.Load in xstream.